# Save values of a matrix after each iteration in a new matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am a newbie to MATLAB. I am writing a code where I need to save values of a matrix in a new matrix each time loop ends. This is the code snippet:

```
for n=1:3
    new_mat=mat(n,:)
    for i=0:9
        for j=1:4
            k = i+j+1;
            if k > 10
                k = k - 10;
            end
            if abs(new_mat(i+1)-new_mat(k)) > 6.97
                edges(i*4+j) = 1;
            else 
                edges(i*4+j) = 0;
            end   
        end
    end 
end
```

this is the code...first two line select a row and go inside i & j loop..i have this variable edges defined earlier in my code which is a 1*40 matrix...I wanna store edge value before n iterates from 1, save this and then get further edge values from n=2 and n=3 and put all three edge values in one matrix. I m stuck..need your help guys

Comment: I can't quite understand what you want. What are "edge values"? What goes wrong with your code? It would help if you could provide a small example input matrix as well as the output you expect to get from it.

Comment: please provide input matrix

Comment: hello chris...edges is a matrix which I already have in my code...it's 1x40 matrix of 1 and 0...for eg edges=[ 1,0,1,0,0,0,1......1]..40 elements like this..what goes wrong is that in start of the code....I have a 3x40 matrix named "mat"....in second line of code I select one row from mat and pass this to matrix "new mat"...now my code enters for loop of i & j...edges depend on value of i &j...so as loop i & j ends I get an edge matrix..now this matrix gets overwritten when  i again go to my first line of code... i .e for n=1:3..what i want is the separate edge matrix for n=1, n=2, n=3..

Comment: then maybe you need to re-declare edge matrix as a cell of matrices. Then each edge{i} is a matrix corresponding with n = i ...

Comment: @scmg: i didn't understood that...

Comment: @codekitty: this is my edge matrix.

 [1     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     1  1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0]

Comment: because for each n, you updated your only matrix edge. To prevent matrix edges from being overwritten, you must have separated edge matrix for each n, that means edge must be an array (cell) of matrices (of different n)

Comment: @scmg: i still can't grasp it completely..i do understand what you are saying but can u provide me an example, so i can grasp it completely..thanks..

Comment: `edges{1} = your_initial_edge_matrix;`
`for ....`
`...`
`edges{n}(i*4+j) = your_value;`
`...`
`end`

Comment: Why don't you just make `edges` a `3x40` matrix and modify `edges(n,i*4+j)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you defined edges as 1x40 earlier in your code, just do

```
%before the loop processing
[num_rows,num_cols] = size(edges);
hist_edges = zeros(num_rows*3, num_cols); %this gives a 3x40 matrix
```

then to save the values put this bit before the "end" that matches "for n=1:3"

```
hist_edges(n,:) = edges(1,:);
```

if you didn't know a colon used as an index means all. so when we say **hist_edges(n,:)** this means row n, take all columns. So we are storing all the columns from edges, into a row of hist edges.

Hope that helps.

**-------EDIT------**
your code would look roughly like this

```
%i simply replace 3 with some variable 
max_iterations = 3;

%before the loop processing
[num_rows,num_cols] = size(edges);

%this gives a 3x40 matrix
hist_edges = zeros(num_rows*max_iterations, num_cols); 

for n=1:max_iterations
    new_mat=mat(n,:)
    for i=0:9
        for j=1:4
            k = i+j+1;
            if k > 10
                k = k - 10;
            end
            if abs(new_mat(i+1)-new_mat(k)) > 6.97
                edges(i*4+j) = 1;
            else 
                edges(i*4+j) = 0;
            end   
        end
    end 

    %stores the value of edges before the next iteration
    hist_edges(n,:) = edges(1,:);
end
```